# The two generate random numbers and their product is different

Tags: java, random, jcreator

So im creating a program that generate 2 random numbers and need to multiply them:

```
public static  int thenumber(){
int number1=(int)(Math.random()*10+1);


return number1;
}
public static  int thenumber2(){
int number2=(int)(Math.random()*10+1);
return number2;
}
```

and solve it in :

```
public static int thefusion(){
int demi =thenumber() * thenumber2();
return demi;
}
```

My problem is when i run it the product of two number is Different 
ex: 7 * 4 = 24

Comment: Please tag the language.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i change the  ( return thenumber;)  to (return number1;)

Comment: I don't understand, why you need `thenumber` and `thenumber2`, both methods do the very same thing. Could it be, that you did something like `System.out.println(thenumber()); System.out.println(thenumber2()); System.out.println(thefusion());? Have you understood the concepts behind method invocation and random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A complete code example would be nice (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but let me guess: You are first seeing the two random numbers (from printing them or some other way). Then you call your method. The method draws two *new* random numbers from `thenumber()` and `thenumber2()`. That’s the point in (pseudo-)random numbers, you don’t the same number each time. So if you drew the numbers 7 and 4 the first time, maybe next time you get 3 and 8, so the product is 24.

There are a couple of possible solutions:

1. When calling `thenumber()` and `thenumber2()`, assign the results to two variables. Now you can see which numbers you got. Pass those two numbers into your `thefusion` method, and it should calculate the expected product.
2. Rather than `Math.random()` use the `Random` class and instantiate it with a known seed. Draw the two numbers from it and inspect them. Make a new `Random` instance from the same seed and have `thefusion()` use it. Now it will draw the same two numbers, and you will get the product you expected.